# Why are my AngularJS directives sharing scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've tried to make a simple directive which displays a name and allows it to be change. When I put multiple directive on the name page they all seem to share the name attribute. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>

  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('person', function () {

    function link ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {     

        $scope.name = "OLD"        

        $scope.setName = function() {
            $scope.name = 'NEW';
        }
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: "<span>Current name = {{name}}<a href='' class='btn' ng-click='setName()'>Change name</a><br></span>",
      link : link,
    }

  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { });

  </script>    

</head>

<body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <person></person><br>
  <person></person><br>
  <person></person><br>
  <person></person><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: All instances of your directive share the same scope since they don't use isolated scopes. Check-out [the directives documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" paragraph

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers, the default behavior of AngularJS directives is to share the scope that they are included in.  This behavior is changed via the `scope` parameter in the directive definition object.

You can view the documentation for the scope argument in this section of the AngularJS documents: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object)

This argument has three options:

1. `scope: false` - the default behavior of sharing the scope the directive is included in
2. `scope: true` - create a new scope for the directive that acts like other child scopes and prototypically inherits from its parent scope

   - See [Example 1](http://jsbin.com/iqusiVi/1/edit?html,js,output)
3. `scope: {}` - create an isolated scope that does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope

   - See [Example 2](http://jsbin.com/iqusiVi/2/edit?html,js,output)

As you can see with the JSBin examples, both options 2 and 3 will work for your example.  The difference is whether you want your new scopes isolated or not.

The directives section of the AngularJS guide has a good section on why isolated scope can help create better reusable modules with directives:  [AngularJS Guide: Isolating the Scope of a Directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

Answer (score 3):

By default if you don't isolate the scope of a directive you will share the "outside" scope with all instances of your person directive. With your current implementation you'd need to create a different controller each time in order to re-use such a directive.

BUT there is a solution to this flaw and it s called isolate scope. To do this, you can use a directive's scope option like so :

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope : {}, // this is where the magic happens
  template: "<span>Current name = {{name}}<a href='' class='btn' ng-click='setName()'>Change name</a><br></span>",
  link : link,
}
```

You have a complete example and explenation over [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) section **Isolating the Scope of a Directive**

Answer (score 2):

By default, directives share the same scope. But if needed, you can use **isolated scope** for your directives:  use `scope: {}` as field in your directive definition.

```
app.directive('person', function () {

    function link ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {     

        $scope.name = "OLD"        

        $scope.setName = function() {
            $scope.name = 'NEW';
        }
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {}
      replace: true,
      template: "<span>Current name = {{name}}<a href='' class='btn' ng-click='setName()'>Change name</a><br></span>",
      link : link,
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options for `scope` in AngularJS directives

1. `false` (Uses parent scope)
2. `true` (creates own scope and also inherits from parent, i.e you can access items defined in parent scope as well)
3. `{}` (creates an isolated scope)

[image: AngularJS Directives scope option]

Let me demonstrate this using $rootScope

```
    app.run(function($rootScope){
      $rootScope.firstname = "Root scope name";
      $rootScope.rootValue = "Root value";
    });

    app.directive("sampleDirective",function(){
      return{
        template:"<div>{{firstname}}{{rootValue}}</div>",
 // here rootValue will be accessible as its inherited from parent. You can overwrite this as well
        scope : true,
        controller:['$scope',sampleDirectiveScope]
      };
    });

    function sampleDirectiveScope($scope){
      $scope.firstname = "child scope changing name - ";
    };

    app.directive("isolatedScopeDirective",function(){
      return {
        controller:isolatedFunction,
        template:" this has isolated scope ,<div>{{rootValue}}</div>", 
    // here rootValue will not be accessible because it is isolated and not inheriting from parent
        scope: {}
      };
    });

    function isolatedFunction($scope){ 
      //define values for this scope
    };
```

Check this [live demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BHPYhtBNvzDAHKG8O31c?p=preview)