# angularjs rootscope and isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

Below is my html and javascript

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{firstname}}
  <sample-directive></sample-directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.firstname = "Root scope value"
});
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

});

app.directive("sampleDirective",function(){
  return{
    template:"<div>{{firstname}}</div>",
    controller:['$scope',sampleDirectiveScope]
  };
});

function sampleDirectiveScope($scope){
  $scope.firstname = "scope value";
};
```

I am expecting **"Root scope value"** to be shown in the expression and **"Scope value"** to be displayed inside the directive tag

Why are both of them displaying **Scope value**?

Shouldn't the expression `{{firstname}}` get value from rootscope as I have changed the **firstname** only inside the directive's controller?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/a1gf9fwc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the scope is the default behavior of Angular-Directives.
For a very detailed and complete answer check this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775531/3686898

Here's your updated fiddle with a new scope:

```
app.directive("sampleDirective",function(){
  return{
    template:"<div>{{firstname}}</div>",
    scope: {},
    controller:['$scope',sampleDirectiveScope]
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a1gf9fwc/2/

Comment: ah gotcha, so i just need to add `scope: true,` to get what i expected

Comment: This or `scope: {}`, depending on what exactly you want to achieve :) (I usually go with a new and isolated scope, but that is for one personal preference and also depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the SO answer link. it was insightful :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I hope you will succeed with your project!

Answer (score 2):

The `$scope` of a directive by default points to the scope of whatever is above it. Use the scope property to adjust this.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.firstname = "Root scope"
});
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});

app.directive("sampleDirective", function () {
    return {
        template: "<div>{{firstname}}</div>",
        scope: {}, // isolated scope
        controller: ['$scope', sampleDirectiveScope]
    };
});
```

Using `scope: {}` provides an isolated scope, separated from the scope above. Within the {}, you can supply a list of properties you want to explicitly get passed in. Other possible values for scope: `false` (the default, point to scope above) and `true` (point to above scope through prototyping).

More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (scroll down a bit, or search for "isolate scope")

Answer (score 1):

use `scope: {}` in your directive